# Error: Could not find an installed version of Gradle while running on android

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm using Ionic2 on mac: I've install android studio, SDK and JDK but when I run command: ionic cordova run android I got this error: 
Error: Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle 
and when I run command: ionic cordova run ios i got command: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0' what should I do to run in android and ios devices?

Comment: You should install Gradle and make sure it is in your path variables

Comment: @devqon where Path variable file in mac?

Comment: @Al-shimaaAdel sudo nano /etc/paths